How to make bootstrap toast animation work?
Hey I'm reading these docs and it seems that bootstrap toast elements has a fuature of autohiding and even some fade out effects I guess.. But it doesn't work for me....
export const ErrorInfoMessages = ({
  infoMessages,
  errorMessages,
  setInfoMessages,
  setErrorMessages,
  language,
}: any) => {
  const mappedInfoMessages = infoMessages?.map(
    (message: any, index: number) => {
      return (
        <div
          className="toast m-1"
          role="alert"
          aria-live="assertive"
          aria-atomic="true"
          data-bs-delay="100"

          key={index}
        >
          <div className="toast-header">
            <strong className="me-auto">
              {language === 'ENG' ? 'Info' : 'Инфо'}
            </strong>
          </div>
          <div className="toast-body">
            <div className="error-message">{message}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    },
  );

  const mappedErrors = errorMessages?.map((error: string, index: number) => {
    return (
      <div
        className="toast show m-1 errorText"
        role="alert"
        aria-live="assertive"
        aria-atomic="true"
        data-bs-delay="100"

        key={index}
      >
        <div className="toast-header">
          <strong className="me-auto">
            {language === 'ENG' ? 'Error' : 'Ошибка'}
          </strong>
        </div>
        <div className="toast-body">
          <div className="error-message">{error}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      {mappedInfoMessages && (
        <div className="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 start-0">
          {mappedInfoMessages}
        </div>
      )}

      {mappedErrors && (
        <div className="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 start-0">
          {mappedErrors}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

I'm importing the lib via cdn
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'" /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script defer src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
...

I tried data-bs- stuff, I tried changing the js lib from min, to just bundle etc, it doesn't work at all....
and so it doesn't work... why?... Thank you

you need to initialize them manually: Toasts are opt-in for performance reasons, so you must initialize them yourself.
